# Qual a melhor prática na utilização de redux para projetos pequenos?

Tags: react, redux

Boa noite.
Estou iniciando um projeto em ReactJS um ERP Web contendo cadastros básicos de; pessoas, produtos, pedidos. Vou utilizar o redux pelos benefícios de compartilhamento de estados entre os componente, porem minha dúvida paira sobre o saga. Vi exemplos de como utilizar o redux-saga porem achei o que o código acabaria ficando muito verboso como pode ser visto abaixo:
Para cada módulo uma pasta com 3 aquivos:

```
>person
-actions.js
-reducers.js
-sagas.js


>product
-actions.js
-reducer.js
-sagas.js
```

Li também sobre a implementação de **ducks pattern** porem não consegui achar nenhum exemplo utilizando **ducks pattern** + saga. E como sou inciante na linguagem tenho dúvidas também se não deveria estar utilizando apenas o Redux puro e deixar o saga para ser utilizado em aplicações mais complexas?

Comment: Opinião: Se o projeto é pequeno, não use Redux. Só irá acrescentar uma complexidade desnecessária. O React já te dá todos os primitivos para um gerenciamento de estado eficiente. Ouso afirmar, inclusive, que Redux é só necessário em poucos dos casos. Vide [este artigo do criador do Redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367).

Comment: Concordo, o redux em alguns poucos casos você pode aplicar posteriormente em um componente se sentir necessidade, não precisa criar o projeto ja com este padrão.

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma boa garimpada nesta madrugada e verifiquei que dá pra fazer muita coisa com a context API + o hook useContext(). Vou inciar sem o Redux mesmo e caso no futuro seja necessário volto a pesquisar. Por hora muito obrigado!